# How do I set floatterm plugin in Neovim such that F5 compile javascript and how do I do it for other languages?

Tags: neovim, terminal, plugin-system, terminal-buffer, init

I plugged `float-term` plugin , that open terminal window in `neovim`.

when I compile `javascript` with node in float term I did like `:FloatermNew node %` then it compiles fine and show me the output in terminal window.

But when I want to make shortcut like this
`let g:floaterm_keymap_new node % = '<F5>'` in my `init.vim`

it's give me error like this

```
Error detected while processing /home/visrut/.config/nvim/init.vim:
E121: Undefined variable: g:floaterm_keymap_new
E488: Trailing characters
```

`what should I write?`

Should we have to write function for that also note that `let g:floaterm_keymap_new = '<F5>'` works fine but just open terminal.

I also want to do something like on based on filetype you working, I want to like Vim script that if filetype is `.cpp` then it compile with `g++` and give `./a.out` output to terminal with same shortcut `F5`.

```
If you don't know second answer then please just give in first answer of that wrong syntax.
```

you can checkout plugin keymaps from here https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-floaterm#keymaps

Comment: Please avoid asking more than one question in a single post ([ask]). Since you’ve already posted an answer, it’s unclear what the best way forward is. I think we should keep this one to be the second question, and you can repost the first one separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can map `FloatTermNew <cmd>` in an autocmd for specific filetypes:

```
augroup floatterm-mappings
    au!
    au FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<esc>:FloatermNew node %<CR>
    au FileType c          nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<esc>:FloatermNew gcc % && ./a.out && rm a.out<CR>
    au FileType cpp        nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<esc>:FloatermNew g++ % && ./a.out && rm a.out<CR>
    au FileType python     nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<esc>:FloatermNew python3 %<CR>
augroup end
```

The `<buffer>` in `nnoremap` makes sure the mapping only works for that specific buffer (rather than all buffers).

Comment: I think it would be helpful to other users who come across this question if you were to flesh out this answer to more than 4 autocmds (a brief description maybe?).

Comment: You can edit it if you want I will approve it.